# Windows phone Silverlight user controls

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, custom-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I am starting to develop a Windows phone (Silverlight) 8.1 application and one thing I wanted to create was a user control. I noticed on the normal windows phone templates  for a WP project in VS2013, there is a template for user controls, but not when in a Silverlight 8.1 project. What would be a good starting point for this? Is it the same as a windows phone user control? I am having a hard time finding tutorials on how to do this specifically for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project and these are the options you see. I believe a Windows Phone User Control is what you want.

The naming conventions changed probably because the new non-Silverlight Windows Phone User Control uses the WinRT naming convention, `using:` instead of `clr-namespace:`, so these components are not shareable between Silverlight and non-Silverlight projects.

[image: you want this guy]